# ZF2 use view helper in Validator class

Tags: localization, zend-framework2, view-helpers, service-locator

UPDATED!
ZF2, l10n view helper. I can't understand how to use my view helper inside of a class.
I want to use it like: `$this->t('STRING TO TRANSLATE');`
example bellow
NB! i'm only localizing project, i'm not allowed to change code structure or smth like that.Also i'm absolute newb in ZF2.
my Class -

```
class Project extends InputFilter{
```

as i understood i have to implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface interface, tried this:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface as ServiceLocator;

class Project extends InputFilter implements ServiceLocator
{
    protected $services;

    public function __construct(Connection $p4, $mode, ServiceLocator $services)
    {
        $this->services = $services;

        //some code
        $this->add(...);

        $this->add(
            array(
                 'name'          => 'name',
                 'filters'       => array('trim'),
                 'validators'    => array(
                     array(
                         'name'      => 'NotEmpty',
                         'options'   => array(
                             'message'   =>  "Name is required and can't be empty."
                         )
                     ),
                     array(
                         'name'      => '\Application\Validator\Callback',
                         'options'   => array(
                             'callback'  => function ($value) use ($p4, $toId, $mode, $reserved) {
                                 $id = $toId($value);
                                 if (!$id) {
                                     return $this->t('STRING TO TRANSLATE');
                                 }

// more code here
                                 return true;
                             }
                         )
                     )
                 )
            )
        );         

        //some code
        $this->add(...);

     }    


    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
    //how to get this method work ???
    public function t($msg) {
        $translate = $this->services->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('t');
        return $translate($msg);
    }


}
```

Usage in Controller:

```
use Projects\Filter\Project as ProjectFilter;
```

...

```
protected function doAddEdit($mode, $project = null)
{
    $p4Admin = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('p4_admin');
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // process add request.
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        // pull out the data
        $data = $request->getPost();

        // configure our filter with the p4 connection and add/edit mode
        $filter = new ProjectFilter($p4Admin, $mode); // 
        $filter->setData($data);

        // if the data is valid, setup the project and save it
        $isValid = $filter->isValid();
        if ($isValid) {
            $values  = $filter->getValues();
            $project = new Project($p4Admin);
            $project->set($values)
                ->save();
        }

        return new JsonModel(
            array(
                'isValid'   => $isValid,
                'messages'  => $filter->getMessages(), // THESE array of messages i want to localize
                'redirect'  => '/projects/' . $filter->getValue('id')
            )
        );
    }

    // prepare view for form.
    $view = new ViewModel;
    $view->setVariables(
        array(
             'mode'     => $mode,
             'project'  => $project ?: new Project
        )
    );

    return $view;
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `tr` method inside a class constructor. `tr` method calls `$this->getServiceLocator()`. `$this->getServiceLocator()` will not return a service locator instance since it'll only be injected by service manager after it has created the object that implements `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`.

So you'd have to pass a service locator instance to the constructor, or don't depend on it in your `__construct` method. Probably the easiest way to go is to move your code from the constructor to the `init` method. `Init` is supposed to get called automatically as long as you get your input filter through the `InputFilterManager`.

Also I don't think you need the `translator` view helper. You should be able to get it from the service manager like so: `$serviceManager->get('translator')`

Comment: i've updated my code, could you please check what's wrong. Maybe i should configure some config or my method 't' written incorrect ?

Comment: You're still relying on the constructor method. You'd need to manually pass the service locator to the contructor -- it won't be injected automatically. Please move all that code from `__construct` to `init` method and tell me if that solves your problem. It might also help if you showed the code where your're actually using that input class, in particular how your instantiating/getting it.

Comment: I'm only localizing project, so i'm not allowed to change __constructor() to init. Anyway i tried to do it :  init(Connection $p4, $mode) - no result. Also i've red that init method is not supported in ZF2. I thought that I already passing service locator manually as parameter or this is not what u meant ? Could u please show how to pass service locator instance to the constructor manually ? it requires some configuration in module.config.php ? I will edit topic to show  usage of this validator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this at all the validation message will be translated by the validator anyway. But your config is a bit wrong I think

```
    $this->add(
        array(
             'name'          => 'name',
             'filters'       => array('trim'),)
             'validators'    => array(
                 array(
                     'name'      => 'NotEmpty',
                     'options'   => array(
                         'messages' => array(
                                    \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'YOUR_TRANSLATION_STRING_IS_EMPTY',
                                    \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::INVALID => 'YOUR_TRANSLATION_STRING_INVALID',
                          )
                     )
             )
     ),
```

Have a read of https://zf2-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.validator.html#translating-messages

You will need to ensure you are managing your dependencies correctly for this to work so really depends how you are using the input filter.

If your not directly adding to a form or using InputFilterAwareInterface on your model you'll need to make sure your InputFilter is registered with InputFilterPluginManager and you retrieve it using InputFilterPluginManager rather than instantiating directly